# Trying to learn basic ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I recently went over a basic Rails tutorial (Railscast) and I read and tried most of the Rails guides, and I'm pretty much on the right path I think, so I decided to put my knowledge to the test. There were two questions I couldn't answer right:

1. Which of the following are correct regarding the method `errors[:attribute]`?

   1. It returns an array of all errors for :attribute
   2. It returns an empty array when no errors occur
   3. It is only useful when an error occurs
   4. It also verifies the validity of an object
2. In Ruby "true" is type of:

   1. Instance variable
   2. Pseudo variable
   3. Class variable
   4. Constant

What are the right answers to these questions, and where can I pick up on details like this. Is there a book, blog or something?

Comment: Your title says you're trying to learn basic Ruby. Your question is about learning Rails. I hope you know the difference, because unless you understand Ruby, Rails is going to be a very mysterious programming environment.

Answer (score 3):

Common Rails questions are usually answered in the [**Ruby on Rails Guides**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org). There's a section about [errors[:attribute]](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#validations_overview-errors).

A good introduction to Ruby itself is [**Programming Ruby - The Pragmatic Programmer's Guide**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/) and the API documentation at **Ruby-Doc.org**, e.g. [TrueClass](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/TrueClass.html)

Answer (score 0):

You say you've been studying Rails, but have actually tried building something? That's often a much more effective way to learn. You would discover the answer to question 1 quite early in the process.

Question 2 is about Ruby fundamentals. It would be covered by the early chapters of any decent Ruby book, the most well-known of which is [Programming Ruby](http://pragprog.com/book/ruby/programming-ruby), aka the Pickaxe book.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if what you cited is literally cited. If it is, then that is not a good source for studying Ruby. If is not, then it is your responsibility.

1. `errors[:attribute]` is not a method. The question is wrong. If it is talking about the method `[]`, then there may be an answer, but that cannot be told just from what is cited.
2. Perhaps, no pseudo variable can be `true`, but any other among the choices: Instance variable, Class variable, or Constant can be `true`. If the question is expecting a single answer, then the question is wrong.